# Make screen reader read html in a span all at once

Tags: javascript, html, screen-readers

I have a button element and a span element.
Inside each of there is a span followed by some text.
My html:

```
<span><span>Hello</span> world</span>
<button><span>hello</span> world</button>
```

The button reads properly all at once but the span reads the inner span than needs to be made to read the following text.
How can I fix this while preserving the same structure as the content of the inner spans are modified by javascript later on?
The current output is : https://utopianii.github.io/span
I want the first span to read like the button but without "button" at the end

Comment: what javascript have you written so far?

Comment: I'm implementing two way data binding with the span displaying the value however as stand alone html this isn't working

Comment: The inner span that is

Comment: The question might be clearer if you post the results you're expecting versus what you're getting. Thanks!

Comment: I want the span to read like the button

Comment: I've add a link to sho what I am currently getting